# Phishing mails to hidden Azure mailboxes

Tags: phishing, email-spoofing, azure

After some research, I couldn't find a clear answer: in Azure Cloud Domain, some users received phishing emails to hidden mailbox addresses. How can that be? How can those mailbox addresses be known to someone outside the domain? Does anyone have a similar problem with Azure and phishing emails?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "hidden mailbox addresses"? If you mean that you selected "Hide from Global Address List", that does not affect outside people. People can still send emails to an address.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure they aren't coming from inside?

Comment: hidden mailbox Addresses , i mean they are in intern Domain and the Addresses not published outside the domain , although they recieving Phishing mails from unknown Domain for us